# Should I go with PhoneGap or Cordova - Which one is free and open source license?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-cli

Should I go with PhoneGap(http://docs.phonegap.com/getting-started) or Cordova(https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/overview/) 
- for hybrid app development in iOS and Android. Which one is free and open source license for app distribution for commercial purpose/enterprise distribution?

I went through all docs(http://phonegap.com/blog/2012/03/19/phonegap-cordova-and-whate28099s-in-a-name/) and still my confusion remains the same.

Comment: PhoneGap = Cordova = PhoneGap

Comment: I think both are same. Adobe bought phonegap and rebranded as Cordova.

Comment: @PraveenKumar not completely true. PhoneGap was bought and redeveloped by Adobe, but Cordova was developed by Apache further into Cordova, that is now a base for PhoneGap.

Comment: Apache Cordova (formerly PhoneGap) is a popular mobile application development framework originally created by Nitobi. Adobe Systems purchased Nitobi in 2011, rebranded it as PhoneGap, and later released an open source version of the software called Apache Cordova. Wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Cordova

Comment: @camelCaseCoder if you doubt what I wrote and believe in that wiki article feel free to write to Adobe support and see their answer, I sure did.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification :)

Comment: @DeadpoolDude thanks for enlightening me mate cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really must go with Hybrid approach, (which I highly do not recommend for million reasons, but that's just my opinion), I would suggest Ionic + Cordova (Apache Open Source license I believe).